# Aspect Ratio with 800x480

Tags: java, android, graphics, andengine, game-center

I know this may be a very simple question for graphic designers, but i cant seem to figure it out.

I am creating a game and the games camera width and height is 800x480.

So with this, what does this means in terms of my aspect ratio? And how should graphics be designed accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

800x480 is the most common resolution on Android powered devices. 
Your aspect ratio would be: 5:3 (which is the same as 800:480 just put in its simplest form).
All your graphics should be created on a composition with the size 800x480, not to have stretched graphics when you run your game.

I would suggest you also have a look at supporting more phone screens when writing an Android game.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this does help. Well i am using AndEngine and as you know it scales for screen sizes so i am using SVG graphics so the images dont lose quality when scaled. So it supports all screen sizes i am just not sure what the sizes of my graphics would look like..For example im i wanted to make a box sprite, what would be the dimensions according to the aspect ratio?

Comment: You should design the sprite box according to an aspect ratio of 5:3.

Answer (score 1):

The aspect ratio is 5:3, but I dont think graphics would have to change. Also, if you are developing an android game, take into consideration different phone screen sizes.